# Temptrol Leaks When Hot Water Running

Tags: plumbing

I bought a new home and it had a constant drip from the tub's faucet. I replaced most of the guts of the Symmon's Temptrol faucet and now it doesn't leak when idle. Yay!

Now, however, it leaks when the faucet is turned to hot. A small drip comes from the handle. What needs replacing/adjusting now?

I replaced the washers on the spindle, but the spindle itself is still original. The hot & cold seats are new, as is the cap gasket.